# How does entity framework keep track if the entity database’s values were changed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

I have the following repository method,which mainly do two things:-

1. Create Technology record (Parent record), and generates a system generated ID for it.
2. Then create a child record , which have its ID equal to the system generated TechnologyID, as follow:-

   ```
   public void InsertOrUpdateServer(TServer server....)
   {

       if (server.TServerID == default(int))
       {
           // New entity
           var resource = entities.Resources.SingleOrDefault(a => a.RESOURCEID == assetid); 
           int technologyypeID = GetTechnologyTypeID("Server");
           Int64 max =GetTagMaximumeNumber(technologyypeID);
           Technology technology = new Technology
           {

               StartDate = DateTime.Now,
               //code goes here...
           };

           entities.Technologies.Add(technology);
           //code goes here

           server.TServerID= technology.TechnologyID;// This what makes me confused!!!!!

           entities.TServers.Add(server);

           technology.IsDeleted = false;
           technology.IsCompleted = true;

       }    
       entities.SaveChanges();
   ```

But how did EF get the technologyID  and assign it to the ServerID, because when I first define the technology there was not an ID generated till I call the savechanges() method which physically created the technology object and get it value . so first I was expecting the `server.TServerID` to get a values of 0 ,, but seems the code will work well. So can anyone adivce on this please?.
I checked the sql profiler and it showed the following 2 insert operations:-

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[Technology]([Tag], [IsDeleted], [TypeID], [StartDate], [IT360ID], [IsCompleted], [PartialTag], [IsManaged])
values (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7)
select [TechnologyID], [timestamp]
from [dbo].[Technology]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [TechnologyID] = scope_identity()',N'@0 nvarchar(50),@1 bit,@2 int,@3 datetime2(7),@4 bigint,@5 bit,@6 bigint,@7 bit',@0=N'H10020789904',@1=0,@2=2,@3='2014-12-20 00:55:43.1567755',@4=47404,@5=1,@6=10020789904,@7=0


exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[TServers]([TServerID], [ServerModelID], [ILOIP], [RackID], [StatusID], [BackUpStatusID], [RoleID], [OperatingSystemID], [VirtualCenterID], [Comment], [IT360SiteID])
values (@0, @1, null, null, null, null, @2, null, null, null, @3)
select [timestamp]
from [dbo].[TServers]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [TServerID] = @0',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 int,@3 bigint',@0=1510,@1=2,@2=3,@3=2102
```

Comment: add a breakpoint on `server.TServerID= technology.TechnologyID;` - what's the value of `TechnologyID` at that point and what's it's DB value after `entities.SaveChanges()` is called?

Comment: as i mentioned the value on the break point will be zero, which is normal because the technology have not been added yet to the DB so its ID = 0.. but if i check the database after the savechanges() is reached the technologyID + ServerID will get the system generated id correctly. and my question is how did this happen?

Comment: check the last paragraph of "Creating and Adding Objects" [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738695(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: then EF will  generates a temporary key value for every new object.? what does this mean ? will this value match the DB generated value ,, or what ?

Comment: @trashr0x i will try ,, but what should happen will it work the same way or not?

Comment: @trashr0x ok now i move the "entities.Technologies.Add(technology);" to be after the "entities.TServers.Add(server);". and EF was happy to assign the server the system generated id for the technology entity. although this what i need , but i am totally confused on how EF internally implemented this ?can you adivce pelase?

Comment: I might have an answer but prior to posting it I need to verify it by actually testing this on a machine. I'll try this on a machine ASAP and post back.

Comment: @trashr0x did you came with any results? seems EF is very confusing on these types on scenarios and there are not full documentation or standards to govern the behavior,, do u agree ?

Comment: @trashr0x did u come with any conclusions ? thanks